# send a post request via vuejs in laravel 5.5

Tags: ajax, vuejs2, axios, laravel-5.5

I want to post comment related to a post via vuejs.
this is the route:

```
Route::post('/posts/{post}/comments', 'RoleController@store');
```

the function is:

```
    public function store($id)
{
    $this->validate(request(), [
        'body' => 'required|min:3'
    ], [
        'body.min' => 'bla bla'
    ]);
    $user = auth()->id();
    $post = Post::find($id);
    Comment::create([
        'cbody' => request('body'),
        'post_id' => $post->id,
        'user_id' => $user,
        'cstatus' => 0
    ]);
}
```

in vue file I have:

```
   export default {
    data() {
        return {
            data : {
                body : ''
            },
            errors : new Errors(),
            success : {
                status : false,
                message : ''
            }
        }
    },
    methods : {
        onSubmit() {
            axios.post(`/posts/${this.post.id}/comments` , this.data)
                .then(response => {
                    this.success = {
                        status : true,
                        message : this.$swal("bla bla ", "bla bla ", "info")
                    };
                    this.data = {
                        body : ''
                    }
                })
                .catch(error => this.errors.record(error.response.data) );
                    }
                }
            }
```

but I get this error related to the line that axios is defined:

```
 Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
```

If I hard code

```
'post_id' => 66,
```

and then remove property id:

```
 axios.post(`/posts/${this.post}/comments` , this.data)
```

it works.
I think the main problem is that I don't know how to write the url in axios with params.

Comment: Where are you defining the `post` property for your component?

Comment: actually nowhere! I don't know how to do so

Comment: What value are you trying to access via `this.post`?

Comment: the id of a post that the comment is written to.

Comment: The issue is that `this.post` is `undefined` because you haven't set it to anything. You need to bind the Vue component's `post` property to the relevant data somehow. No one will be able to tell you how to do it more specifically than that though because you haven't shared that relevant data.

Comment: ok, thanks. do you know any example that can help me? all that I read has a simple url like: post::('/something') not with any parameters

Comment: Examples would vary widely, but here's one: https://jsfiddle.net/tdw28yow/. I'd recommend reading through the documentation: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't solve this via post slug. but without slug, these codes saved me.
in my component send post as an argument to onSubmit function:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <form @submit.prevent="onSubmit(post)" @keydown="errors.clear($event.target.name)">
                <div :class="['form-group' , { 'has-error' : errors.has('body')}]">
                    <label for="body"> write comment</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" v-model="data.body" name="body" id="body" rows="7"></textarea>
                    <div class="error" v-if="errors.has('body')">{{ errors.get('body') }}</div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="submit" :disabled="errors.any()" class="btn btn-default">submit</button>
                </div>
        </form>

    </div>
</template>
```

script part I edit the axios url and put the Argument to onSubmit function:

```
<script>       
export default {
            props: ['post'],
            data() {
                return {
                    data : {
                     body : '',
                     post:'',
                    },
                    errors : new Errors(),
                    success : {
                        status : false,
                        message : ''
                    }
                }
            },
            methods : {
                onSubmit(post) {
                    axios.post('/posts/'+post+'/comments', this.data)
                        .then(response => {
                            this.success = {
                                status : true,
                            };
                            this.data = {
                                body : ''
                            }
                        })
                        .catch(error => this.errors.record(error.response.data) );
                            }
                        }
                    }
    </script>
```

and use the props in my component like:

```
<create-comment :post={{ $post->id }}></create-comment>
```

with this route:

```
Route::post('/posts/{post}/comments', 'RoleController@store');
```

and this function:

```
public function store(Post $post)
{
    $this->validate(request() , [
        'body' => 'required|min:5'
    ]);

    $user = auth()->user();

    $post->comments()->create([
        'user_id' => $user->id,
        'cbody' => request('body'),
        'cstatus'=>0
    ]);
}
```

everything works fine, But trying with post.slug there's

```
message No query results for model [App\Post].
```

error. here is my post model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Cviebrock\EloquentSluggable\Sluggable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
    protected $guarded=[];
    use Sluggable;
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);

    }
    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);


    }
    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Tag::class)
                 ->select(['id','name']);
    }
    public function sluggable()
    {
       return[
           'slug'=>[
               'source'=>'title'
           ]
       ];
    }

    public function getRouteKeyName()
    {
        return 'slug';
    }
}
```